# Using retrained Tensorflow model with Open CV

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

I am trying to use a retrained TensorFlow model to work for live image recognition with Open CV.

I followed the guide [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining) to retrain the model.

The outputted files are shown below:
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvty9.png)

I want to create the frozen_inference_graph.pb and graph.pbtxt file to use with Open CV.

I am trying to follow https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc guide but I just cant seam to replicate it.

Have I the correct files generated in order to make a frozen_inference_graph.pb and graph.pbtxt?

Also could anyone be able to supply me with a sample commands if possible.